# TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseName' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-connection

I've been banging my head against the wall. I've been doing the lynda.com tutorial on essential Node.js and I'm stuck at this point.

When I type `nodemon server.js` I get the error. I'm having problems exporting the db connection in node.js. Any hints? Is there a better way to debug then make a change and refresh in Node?

```
/Users/khebert/Sites/node/airline/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:87
  this.db = new mongo.Db(options.mongoose_connection.db.databaseName,
                                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseName' of undefined
at new MongoStore (/Users/khebert/Sites/node/airline/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:87:60)
at module.exports (/Users/khebert/Sites/node/airline/app.js:22:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/khebert/Sites/node/airline/server.js:4:27)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:901:3
2 Jan 08:04:56 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

db.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/flights', function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log('DB success');
});

module.exports = mongoose.connections;
```

server.js:

```
var http = require('http'),
    flights = require('./data'),
    db = require('./db'),
    app = require('./app.js')(flights, db);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

app.js:

```
module.exports = function(flights, db) {

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var routes = require('./routes')(flights);
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ 
        secret: 'keyboard cat', 
        store: new MongoStore({ 
            mongoose_connection: db
    })
}));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.set('X-Powerd-By','Flight Tracker');
    next();
});
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/flight/:number', routes.flight);
app.put('/flight/:number/arrived', routes.arrived);
app.get('/list', routes.list);
app.get('/arrivals', routes.arrivals);

    return app;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In db.js,

```
module.exports = mongoose.connections;
```

change to:

```
module.exports = mongoose.connections[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with the 'express.bodyParser()', you have to define your connections AFTER all the configuration of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reuse the db object already instantiated by mongoose!

```
new MongoStore({
  db: mongoose.connection.db
})
```